# Cannot cast between UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to use a segmented control to switch between two view controllers. Here's the code for the profileContainerViewController, which controls the switch:

```
class profileContainerViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

let viewControllerIdentifiers = ["first", "second"]


@IBAction func valueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {

    var newController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerIdentifiers[sender.selectedSegmentIndex]) as! UIViewController
    let oldController = childViewControllers.last as! UIViewController

    oldController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    addChildViewController(newController)
    newController.view.frame = oldController.view.frame

    transitionFromViewController(oldController, toViewController: newController, duration: 0.25, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations:{ () -> Void in
        // nothing needed here
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            oldController.removeFromParentViewController()
            newController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    })

}
}
```

I also have a UIContainerView with the first View Controller embedded:

[image]

However, as I load the view, I get this error:

```
"Could not cast value of type 'profileContainerViewController' (0x107917830) to 'userProfileViewController' (0x107917620)."
```

(userProfileViewController is the first ViewController that has to be loaded.)

Comment: What does a stack trace look like when it fails?

Comment: are you sure that `let oldController = childViewControllers.last as! UIViewController` returns the correct view controller?